# Влияет ли на скорость количество сдвигов?

Tags: ассемблер

Влияет ли на скорость выполнения операции количество сдвигов, т.е. будет ли первая операция `1010>>1` быстрее второй `1010>>3` или это не имеет значения? Cпросил своего коллегу по работе, и он мне сказал, что разницы нету, но я немного в сомнениях. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: все зависит от аппаратной реализации. В одних случаях будет различаться, в других - нет.

Comment: Если это ARM архитектура?

Comment: Откройте спецификацию на нужный процессор и посмотрите. ARM - это архитектура, а не конкретная реализация.

Поправка: говоря "конкретная реализация" я имею ввиду именно конкретный процессор.

Comment: Спасибо,уже разобрался, в моём случае не влияет

Comment: Так же как и почти во всех современных CPU (причем уже давно).

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило не влияет, потому что во большинстве, если не во всех современных процессорах, и в некоторых старых (20 лет давности), сдвиг делался на конвейере, то есть за 1 такт машинного времени процессора. Заметьте, что сюда не включается обычно такт загрузки регистра во внутренний регистр сдвига.

Comment: Я бы чуть уточнил,  в некоторых уже 50-летних компьютерах (60-е годы ХХ века)   длительность операции уже  не зависила  от величины сдвига.